# setattr accepts invalid identifiers

Tags: python

Here's what I mean:

```py
>>> class Foo:
        pass

>>> foo = Foo()
>>> setattr(foo, "@%#$%", 10)
>>> foo.@%#$%
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> getattr(foo, "@%#$%")
10
>>> foo.__dict__
{'@%#$%': 10}
```

I looked it up and it has been brought up twice on the issue tracker for python 2:

https://bugs.python.org/issue14029

https://bugs.python.org/issue25205

And once for python 3:

https://bugs.python.org/issue35105

They insist it isn't a bug. Yet this behavior is quite obviously not intended; it's not documented in any version. What is the explanation for this? It seems like something that can be ignored easily, but that feels like sweeping it under the rug. So, is there any reason behind `setattr`'s behavior or is it just a benign idiosyncrasy of python?

Comment: The `argparse` module takes advantage of this.  It uses `setattr` and `getattr` to access the `Namespace` attributes, allowing the user full freedom in naming these, even if they can't be accessed with the dot syntax.

Comment: Why do you think it's not intended? There are no restrictions on attribute names. The restriction is only on the syntax using dot notation, but that's not the only way to access attributes.

Comment: It's analogous to JavaScript object properties, which can be accessed with either `object.propName` or `object["propName"]`, and you have to use the latter when the name is not a valid identifier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A *bug* is something that happens when it's not *supposed* to happen, i.e., when there's some method of communication forbidding it. If there's *no* documentation stating this shouldn't happen then (at worst) it's an idiosyncrasy, not a bug.

There appears to be nothing in the Python documentation forbidding attribute names that are not usable with the dot notation (which is, after all, just syntactic sugar), like `foo.@%#$%`. The only mention is an example of where they are equivalent, specifically:

> For example, `setattr(x, 'foobar', 123)` is equivalent to `x.foobar = 123`.

The only restriction appears to be whether the class itself allows it:

> The function assigns the value to the attribute, provided the object allows it.

---

In a more formal sense, the dot notation is specified [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-attributeref):

> ***6.3.1. Attribute references***
>
> An attribute reference is a primary followed by a period and a name: `attributeref ::= primary "." identifier`.
>
> The `primary` must evaluate to an object of a type that supports attribute references, which most objects do. This object is then asked to produce the attribute whose name is the `identifier`. This production can be customized by overriding the `__getattr__()` method.

Note the `identifier` in that syntax, it has limits above and beyond those of actual attribute names, as per [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-identifier), and [PEP 3131](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3131/) is a more detailed look at what is allowed (it was the PEP that moved identifiers into the non-ASCII world).

Since the limits of identifiers are more restrictive that what is allowed in strings, it makes sense that the `getattr/setattr` attribute names could be a superset of the ones allowed in dot notation.